# Passing and parsing map function in haskell at runtime

Tags: haskell

I have a following function that accept list and operation and perform the operation on that list.

```
-- SUMLIST function
sumList :: Num a => [a1] -> (a1 -> a) -> a
sumList numList oper = sum (map (oper) numList)
```

when I call from GHCI prompt it works fine:

```
sumList [1,2,3,4,5] (*3)
gives: 45
```

but I want to write a wrapper on it and pass the values from file:
{line is **SUMLIST [1,2,3,4,5] (*3)** }

```
let x = (splitOn " " line)
print (sumList (read (x!!1) :: [Int]) (x!!2) )
```

here I am able to typecase first parameter which is list but **WHAT SHOULD I DO FOR SECOND PARAMETER WHICH IS ACTUAL MAPPING**
can someone please guide me in right direction

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to load a file with a command in it. This is actually more complex than that what you wrote there. You have to write a parser for your lines, that should be read. There are parser-libraries, but you could write it by yourself (if you have time and fun with that :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a predefined set of available operations (eg. `*`, `/` or whatever), then the easiest way to do this would be to parse the string and then choose which function to use with what values.

However, if you want to allow the user to be able to map with any haskell expression, then things get more difficult. You can use the GHC APIs to load and execute code dynamically, but the API is rather poorly documented.